# Problem finding correct SDE for Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am really struggling to come up with the correct SDE for the stochastic process:

$Y(t) = a[Z(t)]^2$

where $Z(t)$ is a Brownian Motion. According to my Prof, the SDE is:

$dY(t) = adt + 2aZ(t)dZt $

Can anyone explain how he got to that solution? Thanks in advance, any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply Ito to $Y_t=aZ_t^2$ it simple to arrive at $dY_t$:

$$
f(t,z):=az^2 \\
dY_t = f_t(t,Z_t)dt+f_z(t,Z_t)dZ_t+\frac{1}{2}f_{zz}(t,Z_t)*[dZ_t]^2 \\
dY_t = 0*dt+ 2aZ_t dZ_t+\frac{1}{2}2a[dZ_t]^2 \\
dY_t = 2aZ_t dZ_t+adt \\
$$
Which is your desired result. Recall that $dZ_t^2=dt$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to make sure, lets suppose it said that $Z(t)$ followed a geometric Brownian Motion instead of only a brownian Motion. Would it then be allowed to change $dZ_t$ with: 

$\begin{equation} dZ_t=\mu Z_t dt + \sigma Z_t dW_t \end{equation}$

Thanks a lot again

Comment: Yes, that is correct